# Where can I ask for suggestion about Parish newsletter?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to create a parish newsletter, and I want to ask for information about which software to use, how to format it... and so on.

It looks like there is not an appropriate site on the whole stackexchange network!

I tried to ask about the software to use, but my answer was closed (http://superuser.com/questions/528950/free-software-for-publishing)... do you think there is an appropriate places where to ask for such question?

Comment: Perhaps [Writers.SE]?  See: [Should this site help with specific writing software questions?](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/276 "Definitely maybe.")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite honestly I don't think there is a really good home for that on the Stack Exchange network. SuperUser would have been the closest bet, but the problem is not so much that no site covers it so much as it really doesn't fit this format. I know to you as an asker it feels like a question that should have an answer, but not all question types are created equal. Part of what makes SE tick is the encyclopedic quality that gets developed around a certain topic. Recommendation questions of any sort really don't work well in this format. The best answers change over time. An answer that might have been highly upvoted when it was first given might be an actively bad/misleading answer just a year later if the software landscape has changed. Therefore such questions are not seen as an attractive thing to keep around. SE sites focus on the part they can do well and let the rest of the internet take care of the other stuff.

Comment: from what you say it seems that I'll never succeed in getting an answer to questions like "which is the best software for...". On one side it is sad, on the other it is really fine: I was trying to get these questions answered and getting them closed each time. So, just better I stop it :-)

Comment: But let me say, as a conclusion, that from the asker point of view it is really a pity, as I know the immense knowledge of stackexchange people and I cannot take advantage of it... :-(

Comment: @DanieleB. Try asking in [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access), [The Overlook Hotel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel), or [TeX, LaTeX and Friends](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends).